# Google Maps in Swift - Camera not updating

Tags: swift, camera, maps

I'm using Google Maps in Swift and in `ViewDidLoad`.

I am providing this code:

```
let camera: GMSCameraPosition = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(48.857165, longitude: 2.354613, zoom: 8.0)
mapView1.camera = camera
```

However, when executing the program, the camera is not updating. I am using

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView1: GMSMapView
```

and have hooked it up with the outlet correctly

Comment: Have you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement

```
mapView1.animateToCameraPosition(camera)
```

Answer (score 0):

some times in viewDidload the views cant update its changes, so you can update camera or animate camera in vewWillappear

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 48.857165,
                                          longitude: 2.354613,
                                          zoom: 8)
    mapView.camera = camera

}
```